# Will Bulk API be affected by System.isBatch()?

Tags: apex, trigger, bulk-api

I have a trigger that needs to be run during a Bulk API insert/update of records but that needs to not run during an Batch Apex Job like:

```
global class myBatchClass implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {}
```

My question is will using !System.isBatch() affect the Bulk API job, as of now it is working correctly on my Apex Batch which is what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it won't. Processing of records in a Bulk API job is not treated as an Asynchronous Apex context. The [`System.isBatch()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm#!) method

> Returns true if a batch Apex job invoked the executing code, or false if not.

It will return `false` is code is invoked via trigger in the context of a Bulk API job.

Comment: Thank you.  I saw a post with a similar answer, all of Salesforce's documentation uses the term "batch" very frequently when referring to bulk processing so I wanted to make sure